# different outputs for same input given regarding .disjoint method in java

Tags: java, methods

When I use the `Collections.disjoint` method it returned false and when I created an if statement it is showing the statement assigned for true not for false

I am getting different outputs for the same input given but when given in different form

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //convert array stuff to list
        String [] stuff = {"apples","beef","corn","ham"};
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(stuff);

        String[] l1 = {"banana" , "sauna" , "mushroom"};
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String x : l1)
            list2.add(x);
        list2.add("youtube"); //this is the method for adding extra items or each single item to ARRAYLIST
        list2.add("google");
        list2.add("facebook");

        for (String x : list2)
            System.out.printf("%s ",x);

        Collections.addAll(list2,stuff); //it takes all the elements from the STUFF and adds them to list2
        /**if v create an add all method we could not print the other string*/

        System.out.println();
        for (String x : list2)
            System.out.printf("%s ",x);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Collections.frequency(list2,"youtube"));

        boolean tof = Collections.disjoint(list1,list2);
        System.out.println(tof);

        if (tof = true) //doudt
            System.out.println("these lists donot have anything in common");
        else
            System.out.println("these lists must have something in commom");
    }
```

Comment: The problem is just a typo - `if (tof = true)` should be `if (tof == true)` - or better, just `if (tof)`

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in

```
if (tof = true)
```

`=` is used for assignment and not for comparison. For boolean comparison use `==`. So rewrite to `if (tof == true)`
Or `if (tof)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code that causes your problem:

```
if (tof = true) //attribution instead of expression
```

Add another `=` symbol and you're set.

```
if (tof == true) //doudt
    System.out.println("these lists donot have anything in common");
else
    System.out.println("these lists must have something in commom");
```